# Should this question be migrated to Super User?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

[This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21600/software-to-help-me-reconnect-to-the-internet-without-restarting-windows) should be a Super User question.

His WiFi connection is broken after being manually disabled for a while, and he's hoping there is a software way to fix it.  It's not really a software thing.

Comment: It's borderline indeed. But if you think it should be migrated, please flag it accordingly or, once you've collected 3k reputation, cast a "close" vote. This is not a case for Meta :) I won't migrate it, though, as it's clearly asking for software.

Comment: @Izzy He is clearly asking for software, but he should really be asking a different question which solves his actual problem.  The solution to his WiFi troubles might not be software.

Comment: That's what we'd call an "XY-question". Usually, I'd mention that and suggest so. But the question you're asking about is 1) from last year, 2) already answered and 3) the answer even accepted – so I'd rather leave it as-is.